# Is this javascript implementation of properties valid?

Tags: javascript, properties, implementation, setter, getter

So I am fairly new to javascript and I have been looking into ways to create properties with getters and setters (similar to C# properties).

I came up with this function, but I am not entirely sure if I am missing something that could go wrong. Is this a valid way to create properties?

```
var property = function(instance, propname, acc)
{
    acc = acc || {};
    acc.get = acc.get || function(val){ return val; };
    acc.set = acc.set || function(set){ return set; };
    var val = acc.val === undefined ? {} : acc.set(acc.val);

    instance[propname] = {};
    instance[propname].get = function() { return acc.get(val); };
    instance[propname].set = function(set) { val = acc.set(set); };
}
```

usage:

```
var obj = {};
property(obj, 'prop1');
obj.prop1.get(); // returns Object {}
obj.prop1.set(13);
obj.prop1.get();  // returns 13

property(obj, 'prop2',
        {
            val : 13,
            set : function(val) { return Math.min(val, 10); }
        });
obj.prop2.get(); // returns 10
obj.prop2.set(122);
obj.prop2.get(); // returns 10
obj.prop2.set(3);
obj.prop2.get(); // returns 3

property(obj, 'percent',
        {
            val : 100,
            get : function(val) { return (val * 100).toFixed(2); },
            set : function(val) { return (Math.min(Math.max(val, 0), 100) / 100.0); },
        });
obj.percent.get(); //returns "100.00"
obj.percent.set(33.12543);
obj.percent.get(); //returns "33.13"
obj.percent.set(122.12);
obj.percent.get(); //returns "100.00"
obj.percent.set(-122.12);
obj.percent.get(); //returns "0.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Im still reading through but i can tell you this is wrong

```
var val =  acc.set(acc.val) || {};
```

if `acc.set` is `undefined` it will Throw a error you need to check it is set
before you try and use it like this

```
var val =  acc.set && acc.set(acc.val) || {};
```

Comment: Don't you mean if acc.val is undefined? And you're right, I missed that error check. I hadn't tried defining a set method without defining a val. I'll update the question.